# Are $A$ and $B'$ are independent events when $A$ and $B$ are independent events?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

It is quite basic I think. But I am not really sure with my opinion below. Are  $A$ and $B'$ are independent events when $A$ and $B$ are independent events? In my opinion the answer is yes. But what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for sure. B=1-B'. If B' would depend on A, then B would also depend on A.

since A and B are independent, this means that

$P(A\cap B) = P(A)*P(B)$

$P(A\cap B) = P(A) [1-P(B')]$

$P(A\cap B) = P(A) - P(A) P(B')$

$P(A) P(B') = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

$P(A) P(B') = P(A\cap B')$

so A and B' are independent